# Creating Vim like functionality with AutoHotKey (AHK)

Tags: windows, vim, autohotkey

I've been using [autoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/)recently on a windows 8 machine and loving it. But I want to be able to press caps lock and turn the keyboard into a vim like command mode for moving the cursor, inserting and deleting easily in any program.

UPDATE (Thanks to @MCL for the help so far)

Im trying to use the following script but it wont change the behaviour based on the state

```
state := GetKeyState("Capslock", "T") 
if state
  j::Send,{Left}
  l::Send,{Right}
  i::Send,{Up}
  k::Send,{Down}
return
```

Comment: Cool story, bro. Is there a question somewhere? Something you've tried? Any precise problem you ran into?

Comment: Sorry, yes the problem is that i cant get AHK to change key functionality based on the presence of capslock being on. i can detect that capslock is currently being pressed but not that it is on or off.

Comment: Since you didn't provide any code, I can only guess that you're not using toggle mode. Read about it [here](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create context-sensitive hotkeys with [#If](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_If.htm):

```
#If GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")=1

; The following hotkeys will only be effective if GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")=1
j::Send,{Left}
l::Send,{Right}
i::Send,{Up}
k::Send,{Down}

#If ; end of #If
```

Comment: No need for the `=1`, since `GetKeyState` is quasi-boolean anyway.