# is it possible to map Vim key bindings for windows, just like vimium for chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, vim, key-bindings

is it possible to map Vim key bindings for windows? just like vimium for chrome. I don't like the mouse sometimes.
using vimium, I can press 'f' to generate 'names' for the link, and just press the name to open the link, it's awesome!

Comment: Where exactly do you want to use these keybindings? In Chrome for Windows?

Comment: Sorry, my english is poor. It has nothing to do with chrome. But just vim alike keys for windows(Similar to vimium's job for chrome)

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://github.com/lubokkanev/vim-everywhere) is an AutoHotKey script that implements some of the vim functions in all applications.

Also [LabelControl](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/#LabelControl) provides some label support, like vimium, but it's not always that useful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10510758)

Comment: @WaiHaLee You're right, thanks. I've made some changes, but I don't think I can include anything more in the answer. I'd have to upload the applications themselves.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [hunt-n-peck](https://github.com/zsims/hunt-and-peck) .

you should download binaries from continous integration artifacts.

this is the hunt-n-peck binaries zip link [HuntAndPeck](https://ci.appveyor.com/api/buildjobs/5y2q0atyut7ct6d8/artifacts/src%2FDist%2FHuntAndPeck.zip) taken from repository's continuous integration artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about any existing tool, but macro tools like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) allow to implement that. For a purely modal solution like in Vim, you'd need to save the mode state (and probably also indicate it somehow), which is difficult. [Creating vim like functionality with autohotkey ahk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290304/creating-vim-like-functionality-with-autohotkey-ahk) outlines a solution (for navigation) that relies on another simultaneously pressed key instead.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the stated question: Yes, and there exists several, but they have limitations. The best way that I know of is using [AutoHotkey](https://www.AutoHotkey.com), which can be used to add several of Vim's features.

Due to how Vim commands work, it is only partially possible, as implemented in several forms. [For several examples you can search for e.g. "autohotkey vim"](https://www.google.se/search?q=autohotkey+vim+keybindings&oq=aAutoHotkey+vim&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.4500j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).